# RxJava cache intermediate results

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm developing android client for kaltura video platform, and now I develop uploading video. This feature consists of the following steps:

> 1. create MediaEntry
>
>    *params: name, description*
> 2. create UploadToken
>
>    *params: **fileName**, **mediaEntryId**(which received at **step
>      1**)*
> 3. addContent - in other words bind MediaEntry to UploadToken
>
>    *params: **mediaEntryId**(which received at **step 1**), **uploadTokenId**(which received at **step 2**)*
> 4. uploadVideo    *params: **uploadTokenId**(which received at **step 2**), **videoData***

Here is my code using RxJava:

```
API.createMediaEntry(name, description)
                    .flatMap(mediaEntry -> {
                        mediaEntryId = mediaEntry.getId();
                        return API.createUploadToken(this.videoUri.getPath(), mediaEntry.getId());
                    })
                    .flatMap(uploadToken -> {
                        uploadTokenId = uploadToken.getId();
                        return API.addContent(mediaEntryId, uploadToken.getId());
                    })
                    .flatMap(mediaEntry -> API.uploadVideo(uploadTokenId, FileUtil.getTypedVideoFileFromUri(this.videoUri, UploadVideoActivity.this)))
                    .doOnError(throwable -> {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                    })
                    .doOnNext(response -> {

                    })
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                    })
                    .subscribe();
```

Where API is Retrofit rest adapter.

As you can see from code, i need to save **mediaEntryId** at *step 1*, and **uploadTokenId** at *step 2*, to use them at *step 3*.
I want to undestand, is there a way to save **mediaEntry** from *step 1* and **uploadToken** from *step 2* to using them later, or may be there is some way to change my code, to exclude saving data into local variables?

Ideal solution for me looks like this:

```
API.createMediaEntry(name, description)
                    .doSomeThingWithMedaiEntry(mediaEntry -> mediaEntry)
                    .flatMap(mediaEntry -> API.createUploadToken(this.videoUri.getPath(), mediaEntry.getId()))
                    .doSomeThingWithUploadToken(token -> token)
                    .getMediaEntryAndUploadTokenSomehow((mediaEntry, uploadToken) -> API.addContent(mediaEntry.getId(), uploadToken.getId()))
                    .getUploadTokenSomehow(uploadToken -> API.uploadVideo(uploadToken.getId(), FileUtil.getTypedVideoFileFromUri(this.videoUri, UploadVideoActivity.this)))
                    .doOnError(throwable -> {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                    })
                    .doOnNext(response -> {

                    })
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                        dismissProgressDialog();
                    })
                    .subscribe();
```

Comment: The best you can do is to use some tuple/pair/composite object to have the necessary values together.

Comment: @akarnokd, I did this in other cases, but may be there is more perfect solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using tuple, you can nest your Observables.

```
API.createMediaEntry(name, description)
    .flatMap(createdMediaEntry -> API.createUploadToken(this.videoUri.getPath(), createdMediaEntry.getId())
                    .flatMap(uploadToken -> API.addContent(createdMediaEntry.getId(), uploadToken.getId())
                                    .flatMap(addedMediaEntry -> API.uploadVideo(uploadToken.getId(), , , ))
                    )
    )
    ...
```

Comment: This is not what I expected, but probably it is the only working solution. Thanks.